# Updating variables in flask from html

Tags: python, html, flask

I am building a small app that has a video stream from a webcam and a control panel below this stream that allows the user to enable/disable the camera and change certain modes etc.

For my control panel, I currently have HTML buttons to enable/disable the camera:

```
<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-success">
    <input type="radio" onclick="document.location.href='{{ url_for('set_camera_status', status=True) }}'"> Enable</label>
  <label class="btn btn-danger">
    <input type="radio" onclick="document.location.href='{{ url_for('set_camera_status', status=False) }}'"> Disable
  </label>
</div>
```

This then triggers a function in the service:

```
@app.route('/set_camera_status/<status>')
def set_camera_status(status):
    if status == 'True':
        piCamera.enabled = True
    else:
        piCamera.enabled = False

    return render_template('index.html')
```

I feel like this is a bad way of doing this and it doesn't work too well either. When the app first runs, if I click 'Enable' the camera feed starts as expected however when I click 'Disable'  nothing happens.

Can anyone advise the best method for updating the camera config variables from the webpage?

Thanks

Comment: Why does nothing happen when you click disable? Looks like it should work fine. Are you saying the postback does not occur?

Comment: Not sure why nothing is happening. I even tried executing `document.location.href='/set_camera_status/False` from the console but the function doesn't trigger

Comment: I'm running it in dev mode by simply executing `python app.py`. piCamera is an instance of my Camera class which returns an image to app.py that is then returned to the web page. It's strange that the buttons work fine when the app first starts but stop working after one of the buttons has been pressed